# unable to restore contacts after changing ROM

Tags: contacts

I have changed the ROM on my samsung galaxy Note 2 , i have installed the cyanohgen mod. i need to restore the contacts from my old sansung kies .sbp file backup onto the new CM rom

Answer (score 0):

1. Open the .spb file in Kies
2. Select all your contacts and click save as.
3. In the file name field type whatever you want with en extension .vcf
4. Copy the newly made file to your sd card
5. Import from the contacts app